# how to get sub account under of mother account

Tags: sql-server

i have a project and it has a problem, only about sorting. The situation is, i have an chart of accounts, this is some code and account in it:

```
CODE                       ACCOUNT
1000                  Inventory(containers)
5000              Cost of Good Sold
5100                  Purchases - containers
6000              Indirect Cost
6100                  Power,light & water
6200                  Repair and maintenance
```

It is `ORDER BY 'code'` (w/c is right) but `Inventory(containers)` is sub account of `Cost of Good Sold`.

I need to order it by `CODE` as long as `GROUP` it with its mother account (w/c is `Cost of Good Sold`). But every time I used group by on it just display alphabetically, which is wrong because the other accounts is affected and it does not display as i want it.

I think what I need to do is get the mother account first then after that is the sub account, but after I get it, I don't know if what is the next thing I should do.

This is the expected result:

```
CODE                       ACCOUNT
5000              Cost of Good Sold
1000                  Inventory(containers)
5100                  Purchases - containers
6000              Indirect Cost
6100                  Power,light & water
6200                  Repair and maintenance
```

Here is my corresponding code:

```
SELECT acnt_id, compID_Accounts, fcLevel, acnt_code,    
    (CASE 
        WHEN fcLevel = '4' THEN SPACE(28)+ acnt_name 
        WHEN fcLevel = '5' THEN SPACE(35)+ acnt_name 
    END) as acnt_name, acnt_type, AccountSubOf, fcMotherAccount 
FROM view_chartofAccounts_multiple 
WHERE compID_Accounts = 'b77aa981-bb97-40c7-8227-282f194f2170' 
ORDER BY acnt_code
```

Comment: thank you. this is my code.

Comment: I moved your code to the question itself. But the defined code can't provide the result. You have 4 columns in your code but just 2 in your example.

Comment: Here is not all about results of the query execution, as mentioned by Lonic. How about AccountSubOf field? Is that a reference to the parent account?

Comment: oh, im sorry, i can't add picture yet so i just give 2 columns for example, but the code is what i really used. this is what my chart of accounts really looks like. here's the link https://www.sendspace.com/file/ujnw5m

Comment: Unfortunately, here in the screenshot, field AccountSubOf is also missed too, so I still have no idea about the connection between parent and child accounts.
Could you provide screenshot with AccountSubOf, fcMotherAccount in result of select?

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/rws5oc this is the screeshot of what you want me to provide.

Comment: If you can get the actual hierarchy included it would help in sorting. With this data you'll probably get the correct result with "order by isnull(AccountOfSub, acnt_name), AccountOfSub" If the order is wrong, the accountofsub might requre case for the empty value

Comment: if you can see in the screenshot. account type and fcMotheraccount has the same data, but if you encountered accounting there's a difference..account type has a example of 'cash on hand, accounts receivable, accounts payable,etc.' and mother account is just the '5 main types of accounts in accounting'. i'm clearing it so you won't be confuse. thank you for helping and sorry for my question that not clear.

Comment: thank you for your help Jamesz..but it still don't display what i want to.

Comment: what should i do? use loop in it or stay in order by/group by. what shoul i use to get the result i want? please, help me. thank you.

Comment: As I can see from a screenshot, we have a name of the parent account in a view_chartofAccounts_multiple. I can connect them by using AccountSubOf but it seems to me unreliable and slow. I think we can find a more reliable relation by id in the source table of chartofAccounts_multiple view. Could you provide code of that view?

Comment: "view_chartofAccounts_multiple"
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
   t1.acnt_id,
   t1.co_id AS compID_Accounts, 
   t2.co_id AS compID_type, 
   t1.acnt_code, 
                 t1.acnt_name,
                 t3.acnt_name AS AccountSubOf,
                 t1.fcLevel, 
                 t2.acnt_type,
                 t2.fcMotherAccount
FROM mAccounts t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
          mAccountType t2 ON t1.acnt_type = t2.actType_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
          View_AccountsOnly t3 ON t1.acnt_subof = t3.acnt_id

Comment: "View_AccountsOnly"         
SELECT     acnt_id, acnt_name
FROM       mAccounts

Comment: Could you try suggested function and let me know if any issues with it

Comment: I'm not sure about your comment, because suggested by my order by clause can't affect the number of result records, so it still will be 6 records for your example. Could you give an example what wrong with query results exactly? I'll help you to tailor it to your needs

Comment: I've fixed max recursion error by adding OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767). Does it work correct to you now?

Comment: it still give me the same error. i put it after the order by clause in my statement

Answer (score 0):

I do not have all your data structure, so maybe some fixes of function would be necessary.
Please create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION returnAllParentCodes
(
    @child_id int
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX);

    WITH tblParent AS
    (
        SELECT ma.acnt_code, Rownum = 1
            FROM mAccounts ma 
          WHERE ma.acnt_id = @child_id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT mAccounts.acnt_code, tblParent.Rownum + 1
            FROM mAccounts JOIN tblParent  ON mAccounts.acnt_id = tblParent.acnt_subof

    )   

    SELECT 
       @result = STUFF( (SELECT CAST(p.acnt_code AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                             FROM tblParent p
                             ORDER BY p.Rownum DESC
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

    RETURN @result

END
```

And change your order by clause to following:

```
ORDER BY [your_schema_name].returnAllParents(acnt_id)
```

Comment: hello..i'm getting the right parent and child..but it can't display the way i wanted from the above..i can't display 1 account per row.

Comment: The code above is only to use in your order by clause, it's not supposed to change anything else in your selection, just makes sort order you require.
Do you use following statement?

Comment: SELECT acnt_id, compID_Accounts, fcLevel, acnt_code,    
    (CASE 
        WHEN fcLevel = '4' THEN SPACE(28)+ acnt_name 
        WHEN fcLevel = '5' THEN SPACE(35)+ acnt_name 
    END) as acnt_name, acnt_type, AccountSubOf, fcMotherAccount 
FROM view_chartofAccounts_multiple 
WHERE compID_Accounts = 'b77aa981-bb97-40c7-8227-282f194f2170'

Comment: ORDER BY ORDER BY [your_schema_name].returnAllParents(acnt_id)

Comment: And what's the difference between the result of the query and your expected result?

Comment: sorry, i tried your code in calling in select statement and in order by but it give me an error: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion". And i'll give you an screenshot of my whole chart of accounts and the result i want.i have a 447 accounts.

Comment: I've fixed max recursion error by adding OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767); Please try fixed version of the function